# Editing user's preferences in the same PHP page

Tags: php

I have a page home.php. In this page, I have added one column in the left, which uses include_once() function to add the user's common profile from a file profile.php.

Its like this:

```
<div class='userprofile'>
    <?php 
        include_once('profile.php')
    ?>
</div>
```

Now I want to edit this profile, by using some page like "editprofile.php".

The user should click on "EditProfile" button visible on top of his profile, and then on the same page (without redirecting), he can edit his profile.

How to implement this ?

Comment: Here, jQuery and Ajax stand for this purpose. You have to be more specific for us to give an answer. (I wasn't the one that downvoted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Jquery For This

```
 <div class='userprofile'>
  <?php 
    include_once('profile.php')
  ?>
 </div>
 <div class='editprofile'>
   <?php 
    include_once('editprofile.php')
   ?>
 </div>
```

By default give editprofile class display none property

```
  .editprofile
   {
    Display:none;
   }
```

and when user clicks on "EditProfile" Button With Jquery Hide the Div width class "userprofile" and show the div with class"editprofile"

```
    $('userprofile').css('Display','None');
    $('editprofile').css('Display','block');
```

OR

```
    $('editprofile').css('Display','inline-block');
```

Whichever property you want use it

Note : I am using css properties to hide the  dive you can also  use  the simple  hide and show  function.

Let me know if you want the full code for  this  if you are not good  with jquery

Comment: One question: Can I do it without using jquery ? I mean what if user doesn't support JavaScript?

Comment: Yes  you can also   do  this  by  using get  request  in php but to keep   things simple  use  jquery  and  don't   worry you'll hardly  find any user who  doesn't support javascript these days.